# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value ... of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

```
    private void sendData(int id) throws JSONException {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    String format = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    jsonData.put("stationId", id);
    jsonData.put("patientId", Integer.parseInt(values.getID()));
    jsonData.put("timestamp", format);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl + "/stations/signin", jsonData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("Accept", "*/*");
            return headers;
    }
};
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

I'm trying to send a json to the server receive a response code eg.:(200) as int. 
How can I solve this error?

--Edit: added rest of code--

Comment: Please include all of the code that is referenced. Where is the field "jsonData" initialized?

Comment: Is there a typo in the code between "jsonData" and "jsonParam"?

Comment: Yes but this isn't causing the error, that's just me pasting an old version - already edited the post